# "(TS) Cannot find @angular/core..." Asp.NET Core Angular Project Error

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I have following problem, after creating a asp.net core angular project in Visual Studio.

In the picture you can see the **app.module.ts** from the *src/app* folder
[image]

I also tried to `npm install` in the folder of the project.
I am using Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the `npm install` from the folder, where your package.json lives. 
Also if it's a standard .NET Core + Angular app (created with VS), then it should build & run with the play button too.